# Regex rule segment not working as expected when repeated

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a JavaScript regex to check valid url formatting. My current iteration is:

```
^(?!([^\?\s]*\?[^\?\s]*?as_asd=[^\?\s]*-_-[^\?\s]*-_-[^\?\s]*(-_-)?[^\?\s]*)).*$
```

With the test string:

```
https://www.asdf.com/?as_asd=asdf-_-asdf-_-asdf-_-asdf
```

I am wrapping everything in a negative lookahead to prevent matching unless the url breaks the format. Everything is working as expected until after the second `-_-`. My expectation is that `[^\?\s]*` should prevent the entry of a space character or a question mark without triggering a match, but adding either after the second `-_-` or the optional `(-_-)?` doesn't trigger a match.

I have checked this on several regex debuggers, but still can't figure it out. What am I misunderstanding? Thanks!

Comment: so, the test string should match your regex, right?

Comment: With the negative lookahead, the test string should only make a match when a ? or space character is injected in one of the [^\?\s] slots